# How to set condition for aggregation in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

Let's say I have an index

```
  "products": {
    "aliases": {},
    "mappings": {
      "products": {
        "properties": {
          "id": {
            "type": "long"
          },
          "price": {
            "type": "double"
          },
          "discount": {
            "type": "double"
          },
          "name": {
            "type": "text",
            "fields": {
              "keyword": {
                "type": "keyword",
                "ignore_above": 256
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I need to get all products with discounts in a range 0-10, price range in 5-20 and whose total price should be less than 200.

I know how to filter on fields

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "range": {
            "price": {
              "from": 5,
              "to": 200,
              "include_lower": true,
              "include_upper": true,
              "boost": 1.0
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "range": {
            "discount": {
              "from": 0,
              "to": 10,
              "include_lower": true,
              "include_upper": true,
              "boost": 1.0
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Also, I know how to aggregate the price

```
  "aggregations": {
    "total_price": {
      "sum": {
        "field": "price"
      }
    }
  }
```

But how to set the bound for this total_price?

Comment: It's not clear what total price is? Are you summing the price by product id?

Comment: the total price is a sum of "price"

Comment: Yes, but aggregated over what field ? if that's the total price for all products, it's doesn't really make sense to me why you want to it to be less than 200...

Comment: total price for products which match filter discounts in a range 0-10, price range in 5-20. Such are business requirements

Comment: I understand that, but as it is, if you run your query as is, you're going to get a list of 10 products that match the criteria (in `hits.hits`) and then in the aggregations section (in `aggregations`) a single number which is the `SUM(price)` over all matching documents... not sure that this is what you really need.

Comment: If I have 10 products that match the criteria, but that total price is more than 200 and the sum of 9 products is less than 200, it should be only 9 products returned

Comment: The hits and aggregations are two separate things, the results in the hits section will never be impacted by anything in the aggregations section. You need to read up on that.

Comment: Also what is not clear in your description is how you rank your products